# The suitable tense for a sentence used along "I would not have otherwise had"

Tags: tense

If I want to use a sentence before "I would not have otherwise had", which tense is more suitable to be applied?

> 1-Studying has given me a self-confidence I would not have otherwise had.   or,
>   2- Studying gives me a self-confidence I would not have otherwise had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is better. Also you want to get rid of the article before self-confidence, which is uncountable.

Comment: Thanks, about self-confidence, it is not my mistake. I just copied the sentence and then paste.Could I ask you tell me more why the first one is better?